# Python: Check if given value exist in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to write a function that returns if the given value exists in csv file.

If yes I want to print that line.

If not I want to print "there is no matching line"

```
class Schronisko:
plik=''
def __init__(self, plik):
    self.plik = plik
def wyszukajPoImiePsa(self, ImiePsa):
        wynik = ''
        tresc = csv.reader(open(self.plik, 'r'), delimiter=';')
        for wiersz in tresc:
            if wiersz[0] == ImiePsa:
                wynik = ';'.join(wiersz) + '\n'
        if ImiePsa not in wiersz[0]:
                print ("zle")
        print(wynik)
```

My current output when I check if there is a matching value in csv file

```
zle
Lala;Chart;4;2020-11-04
```

My output when there is no matching value

```
 zle
```

So the problem is that I don't want the function to print 'zle' even if there is a matching value given.

What may be the problem there?

My CSV file:

```
Dsac;Chart;2;2020-11-04
Dsac;Chart;3;2020-11-04
Dsac;Chart;4;2020-11-04
Lala;Chart;4;2020-11-04
Sda;Chart;4;2020-11-04
Sda;X;4;2020-11-04
Sda;Y;4;2020-11-04
pawel;Y;4;2020-11-04
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [for else](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) could work for this:

```
class Schronisko:
    plik=''
    def __init__(self, plik):
        self.plik = plik
    def wyszukajPoImiePsa(self, ImiePsa):
        wynik = ''
        tresc = csv.reader(open(self.plik, 'r'), delimiter=';')
        for wiersz in tresc:
            if wiersz[0] == ImiePsa:
                wynik = ';'.join(wiersz) + '\n'
                break
        else:
           print ("zle")
        print(wynik)
```

Comment: @BłażejBatko No worries. The `break` statement is essential.